# How to through multidimensional array in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get my head around grabbing all variable I need in Codeigniter and then passing those values to the view.

I understand the concept, but am getting stuck on iterating through an array and adding on another array to each of its keys.

The $data['items'] array contains data passed from a model via the get_all() function.  The query is basically "Select * from items".

Each item has multiple features and pictures.  In order to get the appropriate values I need the id of an item.  I can grab this from the first array ($data['items']) which I can then pass to a model function.

I keep getting various errors when trying to do this via the code below.  I've tried defining the features and pictures arrays before the foreach loop - still get errors.

I'm sure my syntax is just wrong.  Any help is welcome.

```
$data['items'] = $this->amazon->get_all();
foreach ($data['items'] as $data )
    $id = $data->id;
    $data['features'] = $this->amazon->get_features($id);
    $data['pictures'] = $this->amazon->get_pictures($id);
}
```

**Edit**

Based on feedback I've updated the code to this (lines 24 - 30 of the code):

```
    $items = $this->amazon->get_all();
    for($i=0; $i<count($items);$i++) {
        $data = $items[$i];
        $id = $data->id;
        $items[$i]['features'] = $this->amazon->get_features($id);
        $items[$i]['pictures'] = $this->amazon->get_pictures($id);
    }
```

PHP is complaining with this:
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/ci/application/controllers/main.php on line 28

Here are the functions from the amazon model:

```
function get_all() 
{
    $query = $this->db->get('items');
    return $query->result();
}

function get_pictures($id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT link FROM pictures WHERE item_id='$id' AND type IN('thumb_set')");
    $style = "border-style:solid; border-width:1px";
    $class = "modal-thumb";
    $results = '';
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $results .= "<li style='$style' class='$class'><img src='$row->link' alt=''/></li>";
    }
    return $results;
}

function get_features($id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT content FROM features WHERE item_id='$id' ORDER BY feature_num DESC");
    $results = '';
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $results .= "<li>";
        $results .= $row->content;
        $results .= "</li>";
    }
    return $results;
}
```

I'm thinking i need to use 'results_array()' instead of 'results()'?  Are my results returned as an object instead of an array the way things are now?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you have syntax error in the foreach statement, you are redefining the $data array.

```
foreach ($data['items'] as $data )
```

Try this:

```
$items = $this->amazon->get_all();
for($i=0; $i<count($items);$i++){
    $data = $items[$i];
    $id = $data->id;
    $items[$i]['features'] = $this->amazon->get_features($id);
    $items[$i]['pictures'] = $this->amazon->get_pictures($id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This got me a step closer.  PHP doesn't like line 28 (features array):  PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/ci/application/controllers/main.php on line 28

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? Maybe an excerpt from the amazon documentation? What does the $this->amazon->get_all() return, array or object?

Comment: It uses return() (not return_array()).  I'll update the main question with the code in a sec (thank you again!)

Comment: Now it complains because you are returning objects, and trying to assign value as an array. Change it to return_array() and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you.  I've modified it a bit to fit my needs but that was the issue.  I needed to use 'result_array()' in my model instead of 'result()'.  I appreciate the quick help :)